# How to fix long NSString crash?

Tags: objective-c, crash, nsstring

In an app I'm working on I'm reading numerical values from a text file in a for loop then doing some calculations and appending the result to a results string.

The file has 22050 values in it. I noticed that above a certain number of loops/values appended (~5300) it tends to crash.

I thought perhaps I have a memory leak, so I got rid of the string appending and everything worked fine. I tried getting rid of everything but the string appending and the app crashed. I have a break point on all exceptions and I don't get any exception.

I wanted to make sure so I started a new project. All I put there is one UIButton that when pushed calls this piece of code:

```
- (IBAction)TestPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *testString = @"";

    for (int i = 0; i < 22050; i++)
    {
        testString = [testString stringByAppendingString:@"12.34567890\n"];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", testString);
}
```

I have a break point on the NSLog line. The app crashes before.

Is there a limit on NSString length? Does it use too much memory?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use a mutable string instead? `NSMutableString *testString = [NSMutableString string];` and `[testString appendString:@"12.34567890|n"];`

Comment: Are you using iOS or MacOS?   If you're using iOS, and using `stringByAppendingString` and you are not using ARC, then you're leaking memory like a sieve.   If you're using ARC, then at least it should be releasing the old string for the new.   @Fogmeister's suggestion should also improve things, regardless of ARC.

Comment: @gaige There's no difference between Mac/iOS and ARC/MRC in this case. Temporary strings just go to the autorelease pool.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I don't believe that's true.   For ARC, assignment of a locally-owned variable usually causes a release after the assignment, since ARC knows that it is the only owner.   I just compiled this exact code and looked at the disassembly and it is calling `-release`, not `-autorelease`

Comment: @gaige The problem is that `stringByAppendingString:` returns an autoreleased object. So ARC cannot magically remove the object from the pool. The only way this would work if `stringByAppendingString:` is also compiled using ARC (which is unknown to me). Then the code inside `stringByAppendingString:` could decide to omit the autorelease because it knows that the receiving code handles memory management correctly. But that's not documented and any speculations should be the same for MacOS and iOS.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe You are correct.  Based on discussions with the folks at Apple about their "reach-back" for autoreleased items, I was under the belief that `stringByAppendingString` would have used `objc_autoreleaseReturnValue()`, which it doesn't, when I trace it.   So, the automatic clean-up doesn't function when using `NSString` as I expected it to.

Comment: For the record, this loop creates about 2.7GB of autorelease pool when run in the iOS simulator....

Comment: @gaige `stringByAppendingString:` wasn't even built by the folks at Apple.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26372/discussion-between-gaige-and-nikolai-ruhe)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new string in every iteration. There are two options to fix this: Either use a mutable string to create the result:

```
NSMutableString *testString = [NSMutableString string];

for (int i = 0; i < 22050; i++)
{
    [testString appendString:@"12.34567890\n"];
}

NSLog(@"%@", testString);
```

... or use an autorelease pool to remove the instances in the loop:

```
NSString *testString = @"";

for (int i = 0; i < 22050; i++)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        testString = [testString stringByAppendingString:@"12.34567890\n"];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", testString);
```

Please note that I included the second version only to demonstrate why the problem occurred in the first place and how to fix it. It is still inefficient as it creates 22049 temporary strings with an average length of 120,000 characters.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I'd prefer the first one. It's probably much faster.

Comment: Yes, I always use that one, never experimented with second one, although knowing this way also possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code will actually crash, because the string you create gets immediately popped by the autoreleasepool. You probably have to write something more like this:

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *oldTestString = testString;
        testString = [[testString stringByAppendingString:@“12.34567890\n”] retain];
        [oldTestString release];
    }

Comment: @eyebrowsoffire This is only true if you compile without ARC. Using the modern `@autoreleasepool` I just took ARC as a given.

Comment: Ah, that’s true. The `@autoreleasepool` directive can be used with manual retain-release though. I work with a lot of MRR code and the code snippet could technically be ARC or MRR so my brain just automatically assumed MRR.

Comment: @eyebrowsoffire Still good to point out this difference explicitly, thanks.

Comment: @Nikolai Ruhe Thanks for the examples and the explanations. One more question. If I know the rough size of the final string will it be better to init it with capacity or it doesn't matter that much?

Comment: @Ata01 If your algorithmic calculations outweigh the string reallocations it's not worth the effort. I assume that `NSString` has a decent reallocation pattern that makes it unnecessary to do the capacity calculation. But as always with this kind of optimizations it's better to just try and measure.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSMutableString` to append strings otherwise too much memory is allocated.

Answer (score 0):

`+[NSString stringByAppendingString:]` creates a new, autoreleased object every single time you call it. Autoreleased objects don’t get deallocated until the autorelease pool pops, which usually means at the end of the event loop. In this case, it is probably best to use an `NSMutableString` instead as the other answers suggest. But if you do run into an issue where you do need to create many autoreleased objects instead of using a mutable object, you may want to wrap an `@autoreleasepool {}` block around the code that is creating the objects so that you don’t have a massive memory bloat, but you have to be careful to retain objects that you want to stick around outside the scope of the `@autoreleasepool` block.

In general, I try to avoid using autoreleased objects as much as possible for a few reasons:

1) When the objects actually get deallocated can be non-deterministic unless you actually have an autorelease pool in your method itself. Otherwise, there’s no way of knowing the scope of the autorelease pool and when the calling code will decide to pop the pool.

2) Autoreleases are inherently a bit more resource intensive than a manual release. Objects need to be added to the pool, then iterated over and released later.

3) Autoreleases get particularly tricky in a multithreaded environment because you can often end up with races between threads releasing an object. In these situations, it’s easy to create a scenario with an intermittent crash that is difficult to reproduce or find the root cause of.

4) Crashes are generally much harder to analyze when dealing with autoreleases. You will often see stack traces that are just an autorelease pool popping an object, and without a repro case it’s almost impossible to determine what object it is, what code path is releasing it, etc.

5) Sometimes, something as simple as refactoring can affect autoreleased objects in ways you might not normally expect. Changing from simple iteration to block based iteration introduces an autorelease pool that might release the object before you have a chance to retain it.

Usually the most appropriate uses of autoreleased objects are objects that are created on the fly and returned by a non-constructor method. This way the calling code has a chance to retain the object, but the called method doesn’t have to worry about designating an owner itself.

That was kind of long winded and perhaps beyond the scope of the original question, but I think it’s important to know the *”why"* behind good decisions in memory management.